# Javascript: Calling functions within functions and overwriting variables

Tags: javascript

I have an array in JavaScript that can go as deep as I want:

```
 var steps = [
    { "step_id" : "1", "step_name" : "Step 1", "children" : 
        [ 
            { "step_id" : "4", "step_name" : "Step 4", "children" : 
                [ 
                    { "step_id" : "6", "step_name" : "Step 6" }
                ] 
             },
            { "step_id" : "5", "step_name" : "Step 5" } 
        ] 
    }, 
    { "step_id" : "2", "step_name" : "Step 2" }, 
    { "step_id" : "3", "step_name" : "Step 3" }
];
```

I then want to show each of the steps in a select drop down box. For every child step, I want to indent it. Here's my JS

```
 function stepsChildren(children, count) {
    var new_count = count + 1;
    var selection_values_children = '';
    for(j=0;j<children.length;j++) {
        selection_values_children += '<option value="' + children[j].step_id + '">';
        for(x=1;x<=count;x++) {
            selection_values_children +='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
        selection_values_children += children[j].step_name + '</option>';
        if (typeof(children[j].children) != 'undefined')
            selection_values_children += stepsChildren(children[j].children, new_count);
    }
    return selection_values_children;
}

var selection_values = '';
for(i=0;i<steps.length;i++) {
    selection_values += '<option value="' + steps[i].step_id + '">' + steps[i].step_name + '</option>';
    if (typeof(steps[i].children) != 'undefined')
        selection_values += stepsChildren(steps[i].children, 1);
}

document.write('<select>' + selection_values + '</select>');
```

This is almost working however in the *stepsChildren()* function the *j* variable gets overwritten every time I call it. It's almost like it's setting *j* as a global variable.

Am I making sense?

If not I've put together a sample for you to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/CJbnm/

If you run the code and look at the select box on the right, notice how Step 5 from the array is missing?

This is because there is only one child of Step 4 which updates the *j* variable to 1 instead of 2 for the parent function and doesn't show any more results...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't create a variable using the `var` keyword it will be global, and you will get the behavior as you described.  In javascript I always use a `for` loop like `for(var i=0;i<10;i++)` because when using loops I almost never intend for the loop variable to be global.  I believe that is your problem here.

Comment: I (usually) declare my loop indexes the same way, but remember that JavaScript doesn't have block scope so (in your example) `i` will be accessible to the rest of the function containing the `for` loop and not just within the loop.