# Javascript Keeping variables in scope on success callback (jquery/backbonejs/parse function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Below I am using backbone js to fetch a collection. On the request's response, I would like to perform some logic on the collection to massage the data. I am modifying the parse method on the parent collection (source types) to attach a child collection (source accounts) and only include a source type if there are actually source accounts.

I don't want to render this without having all the data loaded primarily, so I figure with javascript the only way to be safe is with a success callback.

As you can see in the below code, inside the parse function, I construct a new object called "response_object". The issue is that when i attempt to pack this object inside the success callback, the collection does not include any of the object that i packed into it. How would you rewrite this to make this work correctly?

```
window.AdminSourceTypes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: window.AdminSourceType,  
    url: '/api/sources',   
    parse: function(response){   
        // create response object
        response_object = [];           
        x = 0;
        _.each(response, function(item){
            //get child collection (accounts) from one of "source type's" attributes
            collection = new window.AdminAccounts();
            collection.url = item.accounts_url;
            //get all accounts
            collection.fetch({ 
                //only add the source type to the response object 
                //if there are accounts associated to it             
                success: function(accounts_collection){
                    if(accounts_collection.size() > 0){
                    response_object[x] = item;      
                    }
                }
            });
            x++;
        });
        return response_object;         
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from function with an Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562412/), [Javascript: Calling functions within functions and overwriting variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199069/).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I went with:

```
    window.sources = new window.AdminSourceTypes({
      events: {
      'reload':'render'
      }
     render: function(){... bla bla .... }
    });

    window.sources.fetch({});

    window.AdminSourceTypes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: window.AdminSourceType,
    url: '/api/sources',
    parse: function(response){
        cmp = this;
        response_object = []; 
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        _.each(response, function(item){‣
            collection = new window.AdminAccounts();
            collection.url = item.accounts_url;
            collection.fetch({
                success: function(data){
                    x++;
                    if(data.size()>0){
                        item.accounts = collection;
                        window.sources.add(item);
                        window.sources.trigger('reload');
                    }   
                }   
            }); 
        }); 
    }   
});
```

So instead of waiting for the success callback, i'm just going to have the parse method return nothing, and just have the item get added to the collection if it satisifes my condition.